# What is an .edt file?

Tags: dbf, edt

In a Chinese dictionary software bundle, which I could not get to run on Linux with wine, I found `.dbf` and `.edt` files [[originals](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/download/zdcy.php)]:

- `chengyu.dbf` 
   `chengyu.edt`
- `bsv.dbf` 
   `bsv.edt`

I understand the `.dbf` files are dBase files (their tables seemed to contain the entries), however `chengyu.dbf` did not have headwords.

What are the `.edt` files for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file extension `.edt` is short for *edit*, so the `.edt` files are the edits [changes] of the `.dbf` files.